# Django get user by generic USERNAME_FIELD

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there a nice way to get a user from Django User model making a query with the generic `USERNAME_FIELD` instead?

In other words, instead of:

`User.objects.get(username='my_user')` or `User.objects.get(email='test@user.com')`

I would like to do something like:

`User.objects.get(User.USERNAME_FIELD=a_username_variable)`

Obviously, the latter throws a `SyntaxError`, but I am asking if there is a way to query based on `USERNAME_FIELD`

Comment: i don't get it, do you mean you have a form that have a input filed and you want to return the user that his name is the value of the input?

Comment: I want to write a generic Django library which finds a User (from Django AbstractBaseUser model) with a query based on the ``USERNAME_FIELD``. I do not want to hardcode ``username``, ``email`` etc. I want to make as generic as possible so it can work with different models and different ``USERNAME_FIELD``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [`ModelBackend`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d1317edad0a2908574d2a5b07383bfe58884628c/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L7) authentication backend uses:

```
user = User._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username_variable)
```

This is basically doing:

```
user = User.objects.get(**{User.USERNAME_FIELD: username_variable})
```

Comment: Great anwser! That was I was looking for. Thanks!